# How can I be sure that line segments are joined at the same node?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polyline-creation

I have received a single ArcGIS feature class which contains polyline segments. The segments appear to be joined together at their endpoints, but upon closer inspection they are not perfectly docked to the next polyline. I want to merge the segments according to a specific attribute, but need to maintain valid geometries without creating multipart features. How can I test whether the the vertices of 2 lines actually share the same coordinate and if not how can I force them to snap together if within a certain threshold (e.g 1 meter)?
Software: ArcGIS Advanced or SAFE FME

Comment: Have you looked into ArcGIS topology checks?  It is possible to check for node dangles, and will automatically snap nodes that are within the topology tolerance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create topologies and fix your shapefiles.

[Here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_a_topology/006200000005000000/) is a guide to create a topology to a layer.

In your topology you have to add new rule Must Not Have Dangles. [List of rules](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000sp000000.htm).

Next step is a validation. ArcGIS will locate all of your gaps, and you could fix them.

Answer (score 2):

As per dmh126 answer you need to build a topology in ArcGIS (any GIS software that supports it) to do this.

Additionally you can force nodes to snap together by changing the XY Tolerance and resolution of the data.  Care needs to be taken in doing this as changes need to be appropriate to the scale of your data and its spatial reference.  The help links below will give a more detailed guide.

```
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n00000005000000

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003n0000001v000000
```

To build a topology you will need to load the datasets into a "feature dataset" - if you change the tolerance and resolution of the feature dataset when you import the data will be recalculated by the software and nodes that have are less than the tolerance distance away from the next node will be effectively snapped together (and the duplicate deleted).

Answer (score 1):

The Fastest Way to do it, is tool - Feature Vertices to Point, then choosing the "Dangle node" option. If there a gaps between lines, you will have a points there. Then you could join it manually or use Snap tool.